# Convert a Python list to a multi-column Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Folks,

I have a huge Python list which I created from a MongoDB query, it looks like this:

```
documents[0]['person']
```

Output:

```
{'phone': '3368988989898989898',
 'name': 'PABLO',
 'age': 27}
```

I wish to create a dataframe that looks like a traditional database:

```
PHONE | NAME | AGE

336...| PABLO| 27

335...| PEDRO| 32
```

How can I convert this list to a Pandas dataframe so I can write it to my relational database?

Comment: i think it is list of dict right , can you show us the structure of your list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC with `pd.DataFrame` and `apply(pd.Series)`

```
documents=[{'person':{'phone': '3368988989898989898',
 'name': 'PABLO',
 'age': 27}},{'person':{'phone': '3368988989898989898',
 'name': 'PEDRO',
 'age': 35}}]

pd.DataFrame(documents).person.apply(pd.Series)
Out[920]: 
   age   name                phone
0   27  PABLO  3368988989898989898
1   35  PEDRO  3368988989898989898
```